# Angular Custom Validator Doesn't Reflect Changes in View

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, angular-forms

I have custom validator like this:

```
export class PasswordValidator {
    static MatchPassword(AC: AbstractControl) {
        const formGroup = AC.parent;

        if(formGroup) {
            let password = formGroup.value.password // to get value in input tag
            let confirmPassword = formGroup.value.confirmPassword; // to get value in input tag
            if(password != confirmPassword) {
                formGroup.get('confirmPassword').setErrors({ matchPassword: true });
            } else {
                formGroup.get('confirmPassword').setErrors(null);
            }
            console.log(formGroup.get('confirmPassword').errors);
        } else {
            return null
        }
     }
}
```

And i have added to the form:

```
this.registerationForm.addControl("confirmPassword", new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required, PasswordValidator.MatchPassword])));
```

And in View:

```
  <ion-item class="error-message" *ngIf="registerationForm.controls.confirmPassword.hasError('matchPassword') 
    && registerationForm.controls.confirmPassword.touched">
    <p>Some message*</p>
  </ion-item>
```

But the problem is i can see the console window but i don't see it reflects in view. The `ngIf` condition isn't showing the error message

Answer (score -1):

Use detectChanges() when you've updated the model after angular has run it's change detection, or if the update hasn't been in angular world at all.

Use markForCheck() if you're using OnPush and you're bypassing the ChangeDetectionStrategy by mutating some data or you've updated the model inside a setTimeout;

```
export class PasswordValidator {
static MatchPassword(AC: AbstractControl) {
    const formGroup = AC.parent;

    if(formGroup) {
        let password = formGroup.value.password // to get value in input tag
        let confirmPassword = formGroup.value.confirmPassword; // to get value in input tag
        if(password != confirmPassword) {
            formGroup.get('confirmPassword').setErrors({ matchPassword: true });
        } else {
            formGroup.get('confirmPassword').setErrors(null);
        }
        console.log(formGroup.get('confirmPassword').errors);
        this.ref.markForCheck();
    } else {
        return null
    }
 }
}
```

add this.ref.markForCheck(); after you update the form.

Comment: How i am going to inject this into this static method ?

Comment: Do you have jsFiddle created for the same?

Comment: i don't think it is an issue with change detection. I am already in Angular scope. There is something else missing

Comment: import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
And inject it in MatchPassword as you did  for AC.
I think it should work, I had same issue and resolved because of this. Give it try.

Comment: Cannot inject it. Its plain static class. Per this article it should work without it. https://scotch.io/@ibrahimalsurkhi/match-password-validation-with-angular-2